# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must be StyledEditorKit

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

We are trying to render both `HTML` and plain text using `JTextPane`. Basically the actual content is hosted on remote server, this content can contain some degree of `HTML` tags or none at all. In my `JTextPane` I have it defined as shown:

```
 JTextPane jText = new JTextPane();
 jText.setEditable(false);
 jText.setContentType("text/html");
 String content = "Please view article <a href=mydomain.com/content.txt>Link..</a>";
 jText.setText(content);
```

And then using `HyperlinkListener` wants to be able to render the content when the link is clicked. I am doing so using the syntax below;

```
jText.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener()
{
  public void hyperlinkUpdate(final HyperlinkEvent he)
  {
    //Render the page
    try{
     setPage(he.getURL()); //Error on this line
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
});
```

Unfurtunately when we click on the link to render the content, we end up with the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must be StyledEditorKit
    at javax.swing.JTextPane.setEditorKit(JTextPane.java:474)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setContentType(JEditorPane.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getStream(JEditorPane.java:713)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(JEditorPane.java:408)
```

This looks like when the content has no HTML tag available. Can someone help us resolve this issue so we can render both plain text and HTML.

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED.**

Comment: cant reproduce, works without error as expected

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're saying is that since you want to support both HTML and plain-text from your JTextPane as input, then not receiving a URL isn't really considered a problem.  In that case, you should consider logging/eating the exception:

```
jText.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener()
{
  public void hyperlinkUpdate(final HyperlinkEvent he)
  {
    try {
      //Render the page
      setPage(he.getURL()); //Error on this line
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // either log the argument here, or just eat it and do nothing with it.  logger.error() recommended
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I can confirm we've tried that and all.